# Converting Realm's List<MyType> to normal set or array

Tags: swift, realm, realm-list

I am having realm list, which type would be:

`List<MyType>` ... Now, if I do something like this:

`myList.map{$0}` I get something like :

```
 LazyMapSequence<List<MyType>, MyType>
```

but I just want result as `[MyType]`

How to get a normal Swift array as a result?

Comment: There's a great answer, but in many cases, converting Results or List to an array should be avoided. If you want more info, can you include your use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just [initialise an array with a sequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2907560-init):

```
let array = Array(myList)
```

Comment: @Whirlwind Try to avoid this as much as possible, and work with the lazy version whenever you can. For example, if you're going to reduce the elements in the list to sum some field, there's no point allocating an array just to hold all the elements